# Different processor than the application c# crystal report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I get a warning / loop on the details of my crystal report output. It worked on my original pc i've used to program but when i transferred it to another pc i got this error.

> Warning   1   There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of
>   the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the
>   reference "crdb_adoplus", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime
>   failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture
>   of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the
>   processor architectures between your project and references, or take a
>   dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches
>   the targeted processor architecture of your project.  Accounting System
>
> Warning   2   Referenced assembly 'C:\Program Files\SAP
>   BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP
>   BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\crdb_adoplus.dll' targets
>   a different processor than the application.   Accounting System

Answer (score 0):

Set your application's target platform to x86 explicitly. In VS Solution:

```
Properties>>Build>>Platform target: x86
```

Please note that by default it is Any CPU.

Comment: Can i deploy my project with 32 bit computer with this setting?

Comment: Yes x86 means 32bit and x64 means 64bit